# Adding RAM was recognized by BIOS but not by Ubuntu

Tags: ram

On a Motherboard that allows max 8GB RAM, 2 slots x 4, 4 of them pre-installed, I added another 4GB in the second slot; BIOS reads 8GB available, but the system info shows only 2.9 GB RAM. How can I increase the used limit to 8GB?

System Specifications:-

ubuntu 11.10
Intel® Core™ i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4 
OS 32-bit

```
uname -a
Linux tatcho 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:34:47 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: please show us the result of `uname -a`.

Comment: i am running 32 bit

Comment: Linux tatcho 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:34:47 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please include **all additional information** in the body of the question itself by editing the question so that the question is complete and you can format things better as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ubuntu 32-bit operating system it only supports maximum 3-4GB RAM and 64bit OS supports more than 4GB so, upgrade your OS.

There is a technique called Physical Address Extension (PAE) that allows 32bit processors and 32bit operating systems on 64bit processors to use more than 4GB RAM. Depending on the actual kernel configuration Linux make can use of PAE.

**** you can update your kernel , use this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Comment: i am using the SPM but i get the following error:

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic-pae_3.0.0.30.34_i386.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-generic-pae_3.0.0.30.34_i386.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic-pae_3.0.0.30.34_i386.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

Answer (score 2):

**Method #1:**

Open a terminal and`sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae`.

This will install a 32 bit kernel which supports the amount of ram you have.

After reboot you can remove the previos meta package with `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-generic`. You need to do this, because this way the other kernel line ill not be updated, as you don't use it.

**Method #2:**
 Upgrade to 12.04 version, as it supports larger memory sizes out of the box.